# Instagram media search endpoint always returns internal server error

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram media search endpoint always returns internal server error "Oops an error occurred"

Is anyone else facing a similar issue ?

Have written to support to report the issue twice with no reply from them.

Comment: its working fine, something wrong with your code, paste your code

Comment: `code` https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lng=-122.030318&lat=37.332596&max_timestamp=1468655860&distance=5000&access_token={access_token} `code`

Comment: that api call gets response, i checked, how are u making that call, that code has errors

Comment: I think it needs the api access to be approved for the app in order to query it. I m currently a sandbox user and unable to query it.

Comment: yes that endpoint, requires `public_content` permission, since u are a sandbox user, if u have a instagram posted at a location, search around there and API response will just show your media in sandbox mode